# New WordPress Users registered while site is still under development

Tags: wordpress, security

Recently I started a new WordPress blog and didn't add any forms for user registrations. But I got a email from my site saying that new users was registered. Still I haven't written any post or didn't advertise anything. still Im building it. When I check the site users it was as below.
[image]

Now my questions are,

1) What kind of attack is this. How did a attacker find my site while im just building it?

2)They are registered as subscribers, am I safe to just delete them?

any guideline from an expert will be highly appreciated. please advice me what should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it on WordPress.com or self-hosted? And yes, it's ok to delete them.

It may not be an 'attack'. If you are on WordPress.com (or even self-hosted) it may just be other users that came across the site. There are a lot of possibilities of who they are.

You can turn off allowing registrations in your Admin Settings and put up a landing page to show no content to unauthorized users while you're working on it.

[image]

If you're self-hosting it you can use your `.htaccess` to  allow only your own IP address access while you're working on it.

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^YOUR_IP_ADDRESS$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
</IfModule>
```

Also, just to make sure no one has tried an attack, you can use a plugin like [WordFence](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/) to do a security audit.

Comment: Thanks a lot in your answer. Its a self hosted site at namecheap. Ok I tiked off anyone can register and deleted the users. Am I safe to continue building the site or is it required to reinstall wordpress and build from the begining. Wordfence didnt indicate any issues. are they attackers ? I didnt relese the site yet. im still building it

Comment: You are safe to continue. You do not need to reinstall WordPress. WordFence is pretty thorough. It's impossible to say if they are attackers. They could have been and were phishing for insecure sites to exploit, or they could have been just people that liked the site even if it isn't done. Who knows. As long as there were no issues in WordFence, you are fine. Definitely make sure your admin password is a strong password (12+ length, upper and lower letters, numbers, and at least 1 non-alphanumeric character). And make sure your admin doesn't have the username 'admin'. But it probably fine.

Comment: anyway how did it happen while no user registration form was provided in the site. No user registration facility was provided.

Comment: Getting to the registration page isn't difficult. `wp-login.php?action=register'. You have disallowed that now. Also, it could have been through comments or something else. There is literally no way to say. With the site locked down now, it's nothing to worry about. Just make sure to use WordFence and other security settings to prevent it from happening and keep an eye on it. You are fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Im glad that I can proceed with building the site. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Wordfence](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/) plugin to secure your WordPress installation. The Wordfence plugin protects against brute force attacks and allows blocking ips.